# 404 in browser without cached Store

Tags: 404-page, index, 404, chrome-browser, landing-pages

I'm working on a new online shop for a customer. I'm using 1.9.2.1 version of Magento. Everything is working just fine, but not if I use a different browser. I usually use Firefox, everything is running, I see the landingpage, can move all over the shop and have access to the backend. But if I use chrome, Edge, IE, Firefox Developer I only receive the default 404 Magento Page.
On my other System I sometimes work on, I used chrome more. I have access over chrome to everything like in FF. But with all the other browsers, also FF on that System I just receive 404.
I edited the index.php for showing me errors. On my normal working System I get the one error message for one extension beloning to the Theme I use. A missing variable. But on the other browser I just receive the default 404 page. 
It's weird. 
And I dont know what to do, except starting all over again.

Happy about any help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem today.
We installed the shop all over again. Everything worked fine. We worked on the page and suddenly we had the same problem. 
It had to do with the languages of the store. We deactivated all languages we dont need. But nobody changed the basic Store View of the shop.
Store-Name -> default store view = Your Language
Now you can deactivate all languages you don't need.

To find in the backend:
System - Configuration - Top left, Manage Stores